# How do mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder and com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder relate to each other?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, jpeg

Basically that's the question - how do ***mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder*** and ***com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder*** relate to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former is included in the Flash Player 10.1 ActionScript core library, while the latter is part of as3corelib, an open source ActionScript library.

Both are developed and distributed by Adobe, and the API seems to be identical (at least at first glance) so my guess is they compiled the functionality of the as3corelib class into the core library.  Have a look at this [demo project comparing both classes](http://ntt.cc/2009/01/09/as3corelib-tutorialhow-to-use-jpegencoder-and-pngencoder-class-in-flex.html) (and some more codecs)