# What is wrong with my JPGEncoder

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is my code

```
     if (event.target.content is Bitmap)
{

    infotext.text = "got something";
    var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(event.target.content);
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = image.bitmapData;
    this.addChild(image);
    var j:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes=j.encode(bitmapData);
}
else
{
    throw new Error("What the heck bob?");
}
```

When I run a debug session everything works fine till it reaches to the line

```
      bytes=j.encode(bitmapData);
```

after that nothing happens and my program just goes into limbo Please help

---

I made changes to the code as per your suggestion

```
           var myImage:Bitmap =Bitmap(e.target.content);


    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new      BitmapData(myImage.width,myImage.height,true,0xffffffff);
    bitmapData.draw(myImage);

    var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
    var bytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);

    this.addChild(myImage);
```

but it gets stuck again after

```
       var bytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: are you sure bytes.j.encode(bitmapData);
the code you posted does not have that line in it.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo but you know what I mean

Comment: Just verifying it was a typo in your post not in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I ran into this same issue a long time ago so I pulled up my code from then that I got to work.
After reviewing the code the only thing I see different is I construct the bitMapData first and assign the image via the load function.
So I think your issue is with the construction of the bitmapData var.
The following code block was cut down from a function I created that did a lot of other image manipulation.
So basically it is a cut down version and untested but it should work.

```
var myImage:Image = new Image();
myImage.load( Bitmap(event.target.content) );

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myImage.width, myImage.height, true, 0xffffffff );
bitmapData.draw(myImage); 

var encoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
var data:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);

this.addChild(myImage);
```

Comment: I implemented those changes in my code but to no avail, can you tell me what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: You get no error it just hangs on the line with encoder.encode(bitmapData);? What source are you using for the JPEGEncoder library?

Comment: What is the height, width, and resolution of the image?

Comment: I am using the same library  but I noticed you are using  JPEGEncoder  where as I have JPGEncoder  What am I missing here?

Comment: The name difference is because I use the mx library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723079/how-do-mx-graphics-codec-jpegencoder-and-com-adobe-images-jpgencoder-relate-to-e Verify event.target.content is in fact a Bitmap

Comment: I don't know the whole hanging on the line thing has got me. Almost like it is stuck in a loop. The only other thing I can think of is trace out event.target.content copy and paste that data into a text file and rename the ext to bmp and see what you get. Other then that I am at a loss.

Comment: I do get an image. It's really frustrating because when ever I try to encode it just hangs on and nothing happens. I tried encoding event.target.content directly and it throws an error back

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone runs into this, Make sure you are using the bytearray JPEGEncoder class, it's faster: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=775

the as3core is JPGEncoder not JPEGEncoder.  JPG vs JPEG... this got me also.